# Combine .each link contain function to one if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, hyperlink, contains

I am trying to look up all the "a" tag on the whole page, so I am using the "each" function. And would like to have a way to combine all the link contain conditions as one js, so it won't look so messy. But I guess I cannot use "a[href*="something"]" in the if statement? If not, what will that be? I tried "indexOf", but keep throw me an error, so inside each, cannot use "index of"?

```js
$('a').each(function() {
    if ($('a[href*="typeone"]')) {
      var linktitle = $(this).attr('title');
      $(this).attr('title', 'Typeone: ' + linktitle);
    } else if ($('a[href*="typetwo"]')) {
      var linktitle = $(this).attr('title');
      $(this).attr('title', 'Typetwo: ' + linktitle);
    } else if ($('a[href*="typethree"]')) {
      var linktitle = $(this).attr('title');
      $(this).attr('title', 'Typethree: ' + linktitle);
    } else {
      var linktitle = $(this).attr('title');
      $(this).attr('title', 'Other: ' + linktitle);
    }
    });
```

```html
<a href="https://typeone/something.html" title="the page name" target="_blank">this is the type one link</a>

<a href="https://typetwo/something.html" title="the page name" target="_blank">this is the type two link</a>

<a href="https://typethree/something.html" title="the page name" target="_blank">this is the type three link</a>

<a href="https://other/something.html" title="the page name" target="_blank">this is the other link</a>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your if`()` are invalid since `$(selector)` always returns an object which is truthy. Also you aren't comparing to the current `<a>` in the loop. Can you provide some sample html along with a better explanation of requirements?

Comment: Hi, I added the html in it, hope is more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(this).attr("href").indexOf..` to check if the `href` has `somevalue` or not depending on this change your `title` attribute.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//target only a tag where href present.
$('a[href]').each(function() {
  var linktitle = $(this).attr('title');
  //use indexof
  if ($(this).attr("href").indexOf("typeone") != -1) {
    $(this).attr('title', 'Typeone: ' + linktitle);
  } else if ($(this).attr("href").indexOf("typetwo") != -1) {
    $(this).attr('title', 'Typetwo: ' + linktitle);
  } else if ($(this).attr("href").indexOf("typethree") != -1) {
    $(this).attr('title', 'Typethree: ' + linktitle);
  } else {
    $(this).attr('title', 'Other: ' + linktitle);
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="https://typeone/something.html" title="the page name" target="_blank">this is the type one link</a>

<a href="https://typetwo/something.html" title="the page name" target="_blank">this is the type two link</a>

<a href="https://typethree/something.html" title="the page name" target="_blank">this is the type three link</a>

<a href="https://other/something.html" title="the page name" target="_blank">this is the other link</a>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I try using index of before, it giving me this: Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "indexOf", $(...).attr(...) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to match host names. You could make an object for the hosts you want to match and loop over that within `attr(function)`

```js
const titleMatch = {
  typeone: 'Typeone',
  typetwo: 'Typetwo',
  typethree: 'Typethree'
}

$('a[title]').attr('title', function(i, curr) { 
  for ([k,v] of Object.entries(titleMatch)) {
    if (this.host.includes(k)) {
      return v + ': ' + curr
    }
  }
  return 'Other: ' + curr
});

// for demo only, display results
$('a').each((i,el)=> console.log(el.title))
```

```html
<a href="https://typeone/something.html" title="the page name" target="_blank">this is the type one link</a>
<a href="https://typetwo/something.html" title="the page name" target="_blank">this is the type two link</a>
<a href="https://typethree/something.html" title="the page name" target="_blank">this is the type three link</a>
<a href="https://other/something.html" title="the page name" target="_blank">this is the other link</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```